# AJAX - Finish Execution After Sending Answer To Client

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, output-buffering

I need to generate a huge PDF file on an Apache server which actually takes quite some time. This is done in 2 steps:

1. Check data for correctness and availability - let's assume this takes 1 second.
2. Gather more Data from random ressources, build and save the huge PDF-file. Let's assume this takes 40 seconds.

The client sends an AJAX-Request to the server and gives it some data which is beeing checked in step one. The code for the Request looks like this ->

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "./FinalPage.php",
    data: { CustomerID: IDInput, Link: LinkInput, ..., ...},
    success: function(Answer) {
        console.log(Answer);

        if (Answer == "OK"){
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            alert("Something Went Wrong: " + Answer);
        }
    }
})
```

The Server should now begin to process Step 1 and check the given data. If everything is alright, the server echos "OK" - if not, the server echos an exception message to the user. The PHP-Code used on the server looks like this...

```
ob_start();
@ini_set("memory_limit",'500M');
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(1200);
header("Content-Encoding: none");

$Message = "OK";
if (!DataCorrect){
    $Message = "You made a mistake.";
}

//Let's assume something else happens here
usleep(2000000);

echo $ErrorMsg;
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '. ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();ob_flush();flush();
if(session_id()){session_write_close();}

//Client should have now recieved "OK" or a failure message - the 40 seconds part begins now.

usleep(40000000);
echo "DONE";
```

The problem is that I actually want the client to recieve the "OK"-Message after one second. Now the client should reload the page while the php-script keeps executing the 40 seconds part. The client however waits 41 seconds to recieve "OK" and then reloads - the "DONE" does not appear but it also waits until the script finished executing.

I'd be really thankful for any help as well as ideas about what I might have done wrong - thanks in advance. By the way: These are pretty minimalistic examples, please don't take to coding-conventions too seriously.

Comment: You can call a second Ajax query in background when the first query is done. No ?

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman Thanks for your help! The Problem is that the Ajax-Success gets executed after 41 seconds - when the script is finished. But maybe I understand your method wrong, would you be so kind as to explain it in a bit more detail so that I can understand what you actually mean? - Thanks!

Comment: Split php code in 2, so now just make a query for check data, and another one for get more data. And now you can launch the second query if the first is in success. The second was loading in background

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman Ok now I understand, thanks. But how's that secure? - If I'm just checking Data in one File... And even if i can get it secure (for instance with a random hash key) - how does that change anything? - I'd still need to wait for the script to finish in order to get into the success of the AJAX-Request? Thank you!